# C# ComboBox SelectedValue gets reset on focus lost

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, combobox

C#, VS2010.

```
private void FillCombo()
{
    var data = from c in _ctx.Categories
                select c;
    categoryBindingSource.DataSource = data.ToList();
    cbxCategory.DataSource = categoryBindingSource;
    cbxCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cbxCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
    if (_dbOperation == Helper.DbOperation.Insert)
    {
        cbxCategory.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}

cbxCategory.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bindingSource, "CategoryId");
```

When I choose an item from the combobox, it gets resetted when the combobox loses focus.
Why? What's the solution?
NB.  is connected to Product table.
Thanks.

Comment: Try setting 'cbxCategory' 'AutoPostback' property to False

Comment: is it web ?? or Windows FOrms ???

Comment: Do you have any code attached to the `SelectedIndex(or Value)Changed` or `Leave` events?

Comment: Thank yiu for your suggestions; but there is no property called <AutoPostback>. I'm using Windforms.

Answer (score 2):

Check the condition values for `_dbOperation == Helper.DbOperation.Insert`

i am guessing that this condition is satisfying and the combobox resets to the initial value after every time this method is being called.

Comment: No, even this block commented, the problem is still there.

Comment: void cbxCategory_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isFormLoading)
            {
                _product.CategoryId = (int)cbxCategory.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

Comment: this problem happens also with DevExpress LookupEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in `UIForm.Designer.cs` file, if you use it, it can be that you didn't notice double `DataBinding` line, look for similar lines like this:

```
// Master->Details ::= Category->Products

//
// categoryIdComboBox
//

// 1.
// this.categoryIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this.productBindingSource, "CategoryId", true);
// 2.
this.categoryIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", this.productBindingSource, "Category", true);
// 3.
// this.categoryIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.productBindingSource, "CategoryId", true));
// 4.
// this.categoryIdComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedItem", this.productBindingSource, "Category", true));
```

At first I had 3. and 4. lines uncommented, and had same problem like You.
When I left only 1. line uncommented, it woked but I had problem on validation side.

Solution for me was to uncomment only 2. line.

Maybe it will work with 4. line only to.

Answer (score 0):

For winforms bind it this ways (for strongly typed)

```
comboBoxFollowedBy.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bindingSource1, "FieldName", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```